# select the first element in a xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml like this,

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td >111111</td>
            <td >ccc</td>
            <td >css</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >ccc</td>
            <td >aaa</td>
            <td >ddf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >ss</td>
            <td >MPa</td>
            <td >sss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >cd</td>
            <td >s</td>
            <td >cd</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I select the first `td` element in the above xml. (here `<td >111111</td>`). if `<thead>` not appear in the xml then first `<td>` within `</tbody>` should be selected.

I cannot wtire `td[1]` xpath then all `td`s within `tr` is selected.

Comment: `query('//td')[0]`, in whatever language/query engine you're using. get all the tds, then deal with only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath:

```
(//td)[1]
```

It selects all `td` tags and returns the first one.

Depending on the input XML, this XPath might be more efficient `(//td[1])[1]` (depends on how smart your XPath engine is).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a Union like this :

`//thead/tr/td[1] | //tbody/tr/td[1]`

This will return both the `td`s (`<td >111111</td>` and `<td >ccc</td>`) if `thead` is present and only `<td >ccc</td>` if `thead` is not present.